# Highlight Bracket VSC Tokyo Night

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I wanna ask how to change color of highlight bracket in VSC with the theme Tokyo Night.

I wanna change the color of this bracket `<>`

[image: TokyoNight Theme Bracket color]

...to have the following color:

[image: Primal theme bracket]

I'm looking at Tokyo Night's [color theme JSON on GitHub](https://github.com/enkia/tokyo-night-vscode-theme/blob/master/themes/tokyo-night-color-theme.json) but I'm not sure which one will change the `<>` bracket color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Command Palette using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search for "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" and run it. This should open `settings.json` in a new window.

   [image: Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)]
3. Add the following new property into your `settings.json`:

   ```json
   "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
     "[Tokyo Night]": {
       "textMateRules": [
         {
           "scope": "punctuation.definition.tag",
           "settings": {
             "foreground": "#468992"  // <-- Change the color here
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
4. Save the file and the `<>` brackets should have a new color of `#468992`
   [image: New bracket color]

You may wonder how do I know that `punctuation.definition.tag` is the corresponding property to the `<>` brackets. To check that:

1. Open Command Palette using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search for "Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes" and press Enter.
3. Place your cursor over an angle bracket:
   [image: Token inspector]

Comment: Thanks a lot man